# Seamless grid of elements encapsulated in containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to display a grid of elements with a fixed amount of elements per row. However, for server-side reasons, those elements are encapsulated in batches (of variable sizes) inside container divs.
Here is what it would look like :

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the grid, I want to display 4 elements on each row (preferably using flexbox, but not a requirement). I have not figured out yet how to display the elements of the next container directly right after the elements of the first when the amount of elements is not dividable by 4.

What I'm getting right now :

[image: What I'm getting right now]

What I want :

[image: What I want]

The only way I found to get the result I wanted was to use JS to move the items of the other containers to the first, but this is not a proper solution given the place where those elements are going to appear. I would like a pure HTML/CSS solution.

Here is the CSS I have so far :

```css
.element {
  width: 30px;
  height : 30px;
  border : 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display : flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  width : 100%;
}

.grid {
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display: grid` or `inline-grid` on the container and `display: contents` on the child wrappers.

```css
.element {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: contents;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer in this instance. It's worth pointing out that `display: contents;` can cause some [accessibility problems](https://ericwbailey.website/published/display-contents-considered-harmful/) with certain elements, so it may not be a fully generalizable solution.

Comment: HTML Spec: "The div element has no special meaning at all."  In other words, it's used for CSS layout purposes. So, . ...`display: contents` looks like a nice way to undo bad HTML,

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is set the container to `inline-block` and fix the width to be less than 5x the width of each element and you will get 4 per row.

```css
.element {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 206px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, can you edit your snippet so it reflects what I'm looking for, and I'll accept it as the solution please ?

Comment: What is the purpose or reason for your `container` divs?